# Traversing nested HashMap in FreeMarker

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker

I have the following data structure that I need to traverse in FreeMarker

```
final Map<String,Map<String,List<Person>>> root = fillMap();
```

For simplification imagine this is a sort of taxonomy where I have “continent”, “country”, “Person”, where person is

```
class Person{
  String name;
  String id;
}
```

If you want more clarification:

You might perform the following operations in Java (focus on var names)

```
Map<String,List<Person>> countriesForContinent = root.get(“Africa”);

List<Person> personsForCountry = countriesForContinent.get(“Kenya”);
```

In FreeMarker, I need to be able to list each continent that is in the map; then for each continent, each country; then for each country, each person.

My HTML is basically a number of tabs (one per continent) and on each tab, I have country section, and in each section I list the person belonging to that country.

**difficulties**

I am having difficulties with what goes inside the list tags. I know for example that `root as continent` does not make sense; but I don't know how to fix it.

```
<#list root as continent >
  ${continent}
  <#list continent as country >
    ${country}
    <#list country as person >
      ${person.name} ${person.id}
    </#>
  </#>
</#>
```

Comment: What do you expect from us?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly were you encountering difficulties?

Comment: It doesn't look like a java question to me. If it is you can just use keySet for it for example.

Comment: huh? What are you talking about @JoaoEsperancinha?

Comment: @KatedralPillon You tagged this question with the Java tag, but your question doesn't seem to be related to the handling of the Hashmaps. Your difficulty is related to the HTML page and not precisely Java.

Comment: I see. FreeMarker is a template that Java developers use. Thus this is a Java related question. It's kind of like asking a Django question and including a Python tag. In any case, I don't want to distract too much from my main issue, which I am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.3.25 it's possible to list `Map`-s:

```
<#list root as continentName, continent>
  ${continentName}
  <#list continent as countryName, country>
    <#list country as person>
      ${person.name} ${person.id}
    </#list>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

Before 2.3.25, you can't list `Map`-s, only their keys (or their values). So you will have something like this:

```
<#list root?keys as continentName>
  ${continentName}
  <#list root[continentName]?keys as country>
    <#list country as person>
      ${person.name} ${person.id}
    </#list>
  </#list>
</#list>
```